# how to create mysql query for this criteria?

Tags: mysql

I have to write an query something like this

```
select * from table where title like '% select from tableb %'
```

this **select from tableb** is a query and not a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've basically got it:

You can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
where `title` like (SELECT column FROM tableb WHERE id=case)
```

Answer (score 0):

i found it

```
select * from table where title like '%'+ select from tableb +'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this

```
select * from table where title like (select column from tableb);
```